# Использование 100% ЦПУ при многопоточности

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день возникла такая задача. Мне нужно было написать архиватор для тестового задания.
Для эффективной работы я создавал потоки, в которых обрабатывал информацию.
В качестве отзыва к коду я получил несколько заметок. Вот одна из них

> При декомпрессии ни ресурсы CPU, ни ресурсы диска не используются на 100%. Это приводит к не оптимальному времени работы.Можно ли это исправить?

Возможно проблема состоит в плохом распределении нагрузки и долгом ожидании следующего потока (но это мои варианты).

Мой код

```
var threadList = new List<Thread>();

var supplier = new Thread(Supply) { Name = "Supplier", IsBackground = true, Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal };
threadList.Add(supplier);
supplier.Start(blockSupplier);

var processors = new Thread[_processorCount];
for (int i = 0; i < _processorCount; i++)
{
    processors[i] = new Thread(Process)
    { Name = $"worker {i}", IsBackground = true, Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal };
    threadList.Add(processors[i]);
    processors[i].Start();
    Thread.Sleep(20);
}

var consumer = new Thread(Consume) { Name = "Writer", IsBackground = true, Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal };
threadList.Add(consumer);
consumer.Start();

supplier.Join();
for (int i = 0; i < processors.Length; i++)
{
    processors[i].Join();
}
consumer.Join();
```

При работе с потоками допускается использовать только базовые классы и объекты синхронизации
(Thread, Manual/AutoResetEvent, Monitor, Semaphor, Mutex) и не допускается использовать
async/await, ThreadPool, BackgroundWorker, TPL.

Каким образом можно сильнее задействовать цпу и диск для более сильного эффекта?

Код метода Process

```
private void Process(object o)
{
    //     TransformMethod transform = (TransformMethod)o;
    DataBlock dataBlock;

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (!queue1.TryDequeue(out dataBlock, timeout: 100) && !_aborting && !_exiting) ;
            if (_aborting || _exiting) break;

            if (dataBlock.Size == 0)
            {
                while (!queue2.TryEnqueue(dataBlock, timeout: 100) && !_aborting) ;
                _exiting = true;
                break;
            }
            if (_isCompress)
            {
                CompressMethod(dataBlock);
            }
            else
            {
                DecompressMethod(dataBlock);
            }

            while (!queue2.TryEnqueue(dataBlock, timeout: 100) && !_aborting) ;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _exception = e;
        _aborting = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь всё нормально, нужно смотреть на метод `Process`

Comment: @Zergatul Добавил код метода

Comment: Профилитровать пробовали свои потоки? Или логгиррвать хотя бы их работу? Они где то простаивают? `Thread.Sleep(...);` не злоупотребляете? На диск пишете с буфером?